# Adding a TTF font to LaTeX: Which encoding?

Tags: fonts, errors, font-encodings, truetype

The TTF font called *Remeslo* is available at several sites including [Wfonts](https://www.wfonts.com/font/remeslo). I tried to follow posts on this site to add it by generating the following files:

```
Remeslo.tfm
Remeslo.afm
Remeslo.vpl
Remeslo.vf
Remeslo.fd
```

The contents of the `.fd` file are as follows:

```
%Filename:      Remeslo.fd
%Created by:    Me
%Creation date: 2019/11/12

% This file should be put in a TeX input directory

\ProvidesFile{Remeslo.fd}
   [2019/11/12 Font definition file for U/Remeslo]

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{Remeslo}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{Remeslo}{xl}{n}{
   <-> Remeslo
}{}

\endinput
```

I followed another `.fd` file and apparently got the `U` encoding wrong. So, let us start with the "minimal" MWE first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input Remeslo.fd
\newcommand*\remfamily{\usefont{U}{Remeslo}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
%\remfamily
\fontsize{12mm}{12mm}
\selectfont
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE GREAZY DOG

\end{document}
```

If the commented line is uncommented, the error is:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [max level recursion of virtual fonts=10]. \end{document}

If, however, I use Russian characters in the "more realistic" MWE, the error is different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\input Remeslo.fd
\newcommand*\remfamily{\usefont{U}{Remeslo}{xl}{n}}

\begin{document}
\remfamily
\fontsize{12mm}{12mm}
\selectfont
БЫСТРЫЙ ЛИС ПРЫГАЕТ ЧЕРЕЗ ЖИРНУЮ СОБАКУ
\end{document}
```

There are as many errors as Russian characters:

> Command \CYRB unavailable in encoding U. Б
>
> Command \CYRERY unavailable in encoding U. БЫ
>
> Command \CYRS unavailable in encoding U. БЫС
>
> Command \CYRT unavailable in encoding U. БЫСТ

etc. What am I missing in the font configuration?

---

I can use neither Lualatex nor Xelatex due to the issues with the quality of the documents that they render. I had established that the safest approach is to try to load a TTF font due to many issues with other tools.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use the font directly with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: if the font is a textfont U encoding is completly wrong - that is meant for arbitrary symbol fonts.

Comment: But beside this: max level recursion of virtual fonts=10 probably means that the vf/vpl file is faulty. How did you generate the files??

Comment: Your comment about the "quality" of Lua/XeLaTeX documents might warrant a separate question, since there should be few discernible differences in output among the three engines.  Can you ask a new question showing a document that, when compiled with LuaLaTeX and/or XeLaTeX produces bad output compared to the same document produced with pdfLaTeX?